# Step not working for an input in HTML - the field is accepting any number of decimal places

Tags: javascript, input, numbers, decimal

I am using a simple number input and I have removed spinners so users can input their own number. The full input code is:

```
<input type="number" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" id="userInputMapOne" class="form-control" min="0" step="0.01" aria-label="input value for your zone">
```

But I discovered a user can input larger number of decimal places than the 0.01 step required. This is annoying. On my other part of the page the step attribute works perfectly. The only difference in this particular code is I am using a bootstrap prepend forms. Otherwise there's no difference.

The input sends a value to a JavaScript function, but it would be nice if that function limited the input to two decimal places.

What code should I use for JS to not accept any decimal places more than 2 d.p?

Should I do an if > 0.99 or < 0.00 ? There must be a JS code for decimal places too, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<input type="number" onkeyup="return isNumberKey(this, 2)" id="userInputMapOne" class="form-control" min="0" step="0.01" aria-label="input value for your zone">

function isNumberKey(obj, decimals) {
    if (obj.value % Math.round(obj.value)) {
        var divisor = Math.pow(10, decimals);
        obj.value = Math.floor(obj.value * divisor)/divisor;
    }

    console.log(obj.value);
 }
```

**NOTE:**

I used `onkeyup`, which is when you want it to change.

**EDIT:**

If you need to also check for numbers only:

```
<input type="number" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onkeyup="return truncateDecimals(this, 4)" id="userInputMapOne" class="form-control" min="0" step="0.01" aria-label="input value for your zone">

function isNumberKey(evt) {
    let charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode; 
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && charCode != 46) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
 }

 function truncateDecimals(obj, decimals) {
    if (obj.value % Math.round(obj.value)) {
      
        var divisor = Math.pow(10, decimals);
        obj.value = Math.floor(obj.value * divisor)/divisor;
    }

    console.log(obj.value);
    return true;
 }
```

Comment: Note I changed to Math.floor(), which truncates instead of rounds.  That way, your value doesn't drift if they type `123.456789`

Comment: Also, I didn't see this, but it stops my other isNumberKey from functioning. How do you string two together correctly?

onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onkeyup="return isNumberKey(this, 2)"

Comment: How is the other used?  You may need 2 functions. `onkeyup="return truncateDecimals(this, 2)"`

Comment: The other one is to stop non-number key inputs.

Comment: ` function isNumberKey(evt) {
  let charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && charCode != 46)
    return false;
  return true;
} `

Comment: `<input type="number"...> should accomplish that. But we can merge the 2 functions.  See edit

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not seem to get both to work at the same time.

Comment: I cannot enter letters with `input type="number"` what browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox - But it happens in Chrome too. I removed spinners, that's the only thing I did differently.

Comment: This happened on my other page too and I don't know why. I use type="number" and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I did just try on my phone and it seems to work. So maybe it is just my browser then? I really do not know.